# React + Electron, content security policy блокирует fetch запросы из компонента React к сторонним api

Tags: reactjs, fetch, electron, csp

Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему с **Content security policy.**

Проблема заключается в следующем:

При помощи **Electron Forge** внедрил свое **ReactJS** приложение в **ElectronJS**, но возникла проблема с политикой безопасности, а конкретно - **Electron** не дает выполнять **fetch** запросы на сторонний **API** (проблема еще усугубляется тем, что **API** домен без **SSL**, простой **http://**).

**Fetch** запрос выполняется из компонента **App** при первом рендере **(ComponentDidMount)**, но он сразу же блокируется.

Пытался работать с **CSP** и через **manifest.json**, и через главный файл **Electron**, и что то там делал  с другими конфигурациями  тегов, но все тщетно.

Отключил web безопасность в электрон, разрешил подключение к протоколам *http/https* (`webPreferences: {webSecurity: false, allowRunningInsecureContent: true}`) тоже никак не влияет на ситуацию.

Метод который давал хоть какую то реакцию это - через: `<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" ...>`,
прописывал различные конфигурации.

При добавлении домена с **API** в **connect-src** ошибка с доменом API вроде как пропадает, но появляется при этом та же проблема что и с **API**, но только с **http://localhost:3000**, если добавляю **http://localhost:3000** к **connect-src** через пробел, все возвращается к исходному результату и в ошибке написано, что **connect-src** явно не определен и применен **default-src 'self'** (хоть он и с другим значением).

Проблема с **http(ws)://localhost:3000** решается вот этой конфигурацией:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="default-src 'unsafe-eval';
                  script-src-elem http:;
                  connect-src ws: http: http://data.fixer.io/;
                  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Но никак не решает проблему с блокировкой **API** (http://data.fixer.io/) даже добавив его в список **connect-src**.
В консоли вот это:
[image: Вывод в консоли]
Пишет что **connect-src** явно не указан, хотя он указан и работает для **http(ws)://localhost:3000**. Либо я чего не понимаю...

Перечитал тонну различной информации на англоязычных сайтах, но не нашел ничего рабочего, в рунете тоже ничего.

Вот ссылка на сам проект в GitHub [ссылка на проект](https://github.com/vv-tomilin/electron_currency_app)

***P.S.*** Само приложение **ReactJS** без **Electron** работает корректно, все **fetch** запросы отрабатывают так как запланировано.

***P.P.S.*** Прошу сильно не ругать, я новичек во всем этом, и это мое первое учебное приложение в связке React + Electron. Спасибо за понимание!

Заранее благодарен за любую информацию, которая даст хотя бы правильное направление для поиска решения проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

> `connect-src` явно не определен и применен `default-src 'self'` (хоть он и с другим значением).

У вас уже публикуется Content Security Policy (CSP), поэтому добавленный вами метатег не работает. Он просто добавляет вторую CSP, но первая продолжает всё блокировать. Это как раз и видно видно по блокирующим правилам: `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:` - они от первой CSP, а не из вашего мета тега.

Поэтому вам надо найти где публикуется первая CSP и добавить источник `http://data.fixer.io` в неё.

В режиме Prod CSP в Электрон публикуется только посредством метатега.
В режиме Dev (а судя по `http(ws)://localhost:3000` в находитесь в режиме Разработки), CSP также может быть опубликована посредством HTTP-заголовка. Проверьте, не издаёте ли вы [CSP в HTTP-заголовке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629) (оно на Eng, но там важна только картинка).

Проверьте наличие в коде вашего Приложения участка:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
  callback({ responseHeaders: Object.assign({
    ...details.responseHeaders,
    "Content-Security-Policy": [ "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:" ]
    }, details.responseHeaders)});
  });
```

он может издавать заголовок CSP в режиме Dev. Также CSP заголовок могут издавать плагины `electron-forge` и `electron-forge/plugin-webpack` - у них есть настройка CSP для режима разработки (Dev).

И проверьте HTML код вашего приложения в браузере на наличие второго мета тега `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`, поскольку плагины могут публиковать его и посредством мета тега тоже. Тогда в HTML коде будет 2 мета тега: один ваш, второй от плагина.

Замечание. Описываемое вами поведение при добавлении `http(ws)://localhost:3000` - это ложный след, `localhost` обычно покрывается токеном `'self'`, который у вас есть в обеих CSP.
`ws://localhost:3000` нужен только если используются вебсокеты, для обычных [fetch-запросов достаточно](http://csplite.com/ru/csp/test25/) `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: Я тоже подозревал, что уже публикуется **Content Security Policy (CSP)** где то в другом месте, но не смог найти где это может быть прописано еще. Действительно **CSP** опубликована посредством **HTTP-заголовка** и якобы генерируется в файле **index.js** Реакта (где ReactDOM.render()), возможно это и правда, но я не знаю как это можно узнать и исправить. @granty

Comment: По поводу вашего замечания о _"добавлении http(ws)://localhost:3000 - это ложный след"_ я с вами согласен, но не понимаю как можно это решить. @granty

Comment: Через **session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {...}** я сам пытался прописывать **CSP**, но результат точно такой же, как и с **<meta>** (пробовал применять их совместно и по отдельности). Второго **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"** в **HTML** нет. Перерыл все файлы и не нашел ничего, что могло бы устанавливать CSP. Если интересно, то вот ссылка на сам проект в GitHub (еще добавлю в описание): https://github.com/vv-tomilin/electron_currency_app @granty

Comment: Если используете веб-сервер Nginx, проверьте строку `add_header Content-Security-Policy ...` в конфиге. В случае Apache - `Header set Content-Security-Policy ...` в `.htaccess` или в конфиге. Webpack тоже имеет плагины, которые могут издавать CSP.